# not able to return stream data in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

Below is the code I have written:

```
router.get('/all-outlets', (_req, res) => {
  console.log('jererere');
  // var sql = knex.select('*').from('retail_outletsss').limit(10);
  let stream = knex.raw(`select * from retail_outlets limit 1;`).stream();
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
});
```

While executing this, it is not returning any data, rather it is stuck in loop.

Comment: `JSONStream.stringfy()` is reponse of the function, you may use `stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify).pipe(res);` instead of `stream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);`

Comment: getting issues while using JSONStream.stringify only

error TS2345: Argument of type '{ (): ReadWriteStream; (newlineOnly: false): ReadWriteStream; (open: string, sep: string, close: string): ReadWriteStream; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableStream'.
  Type '{ (): ReadWriteStream; (newlineOnly: false): ReadWriteStream; (open: string, sep: string, close: string): ReadWriteStream; }' is missing the following properties from type 'WritableStream': writable, write, end, addListener, and 14 more.

Answer (score 0):

Above code will work. But you need to have package
"pg-query-stream"
installed for postgres.